# How to select an id that is equal to the value of dropdown list item

Tags: javascript, html

I want to show a row of a table based on selection from a drop-down list.

By default all rows will be hidden. When the user makes a selection from the drop-down list, I want the row with id equal to the value of the selection to become visible.

But I can't seem to successfully compare drop-down selection value to row id.

Can you please help?

```
<table id = "stats" style="width: 50%;">
            <caption style="caption-side: top; font-weight: bold; font-size:small; padding:20px">Michael Jordan's Stats</caption>
            <tr style="color: red; font-size: large; border: 1px solid black;">
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>G</th>
                <th>PTS</th>
                <th>REB</th>
                <th>AST</th>
            </tr>

            <tr id="84" class=hidden-cell>
                <td>84-85</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>28.2</td>
                <td>6.5</td>
                <td>5.9</td>
            </tr>

            </tr>
            <tr id="85" class=hidden-cell>
                <td>85-86</td>
                <td>18</td>
                <td>22.7</td>
                <td>3.6</td>
                <td>2.9</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="86" class=hidden-cell>
                <td>86-87</td>
                <td>82</td>
                <td>37.1</td>
                <td>5.2</td>
                <td>4.6</td>
            </tr>
</table>*

<select id="year">
            <option value="84">84-85</option>
            <option value="85">85-86</option>
            <option value="86">86-87</option>

</select>

        <button type="button" onclick="select_year()">Select</button>

        <p>Click the button to select season</p>

        <script>

        function select_year()
        {
            var x = document.querySelector('#year').value;

            var table = document.getElementById("stats");
            var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
            {
                var y = trs[i].id
                if (x.intValue() == (trs[i].id).intValue())
                {
                   //Here I want to test with an alert to confirm the compare function is 
                     working but it is not working.
                   alert(x);
                }
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: x.intValue is not a function
    at select_year (Detailed Stats.html:166)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Detailed Stats.html:150)

Comment: Do you mean `parseInt`? `intValue` is a Java function I believe.

Comment: Well that's a pretty clear description of the problem. There is no `.intValue()` function for strings. You don't need to do all that work anyway; you can just prepend a "#" character on the selector value and use `document.querySelector()` to find the `<tr>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table id = "stats" style="width: 50%;">
   <caption style="caption-side: top; font-weight: bold; font-size:small; padding:20px">Michael Jordan's Stats</caption>
   <tr style="color: red; font-size: large; border: 1px solid black;">
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>G</th>
      <th>PTS</th>
      <th>REB</th>
      <th>AST</th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="84" class=hidden-cell>
      <td>84-85</td>
      <td>82</td>
      <td>28.2</td>
      <td>6.5</td>
      <td>5.9</td>
   </tr>
   </tr>
   <tr id="85" class=hidden-cell>
      <td>85-86</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>22.7</td>
      <td>3.6</td>
      <td>2.9</td>
   </tr>
   <tr id="86" class=hidden-cell>
      <td>86-87</td>
      <td>82</td>
      <td>37.1</td>
      <td>5.2</td>
      <td>4.6</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<select id="year">
   <option value="84">84-85</option>
   <option value="85">85-86</option>
   <option value="86">86-87</option>
</select>
<p>Click the button to select season</p>
<script>
   function select_year(){
       var x = document.querySelector('#year').value;

       var table = document.getElementById("stats");
       var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

       for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
       {
           var y = trs[i].id

           if (+x === +trs[i].id)
           {
              //Here I want to test with an alert to confirm the compare function is 
               //working but it is not working.
              alert(x);
           }
       }
   }

</script>
<button type="button" onclick="select_year()">Select</button>
```

`intValue` is not a function in Javascript. You should either use

`parseInt` or unary operator `+` to convert string to a number.

Answer (score 0):

intValue() is not a valid javascript function

Try parseInt(), as shown below

```
function select_year()
        {
            var x = document.querySelector('#year').value;

            var table = document.getElementById("stats");
            var trs = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

            for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++)
            {
                var y = trs[i].id
                if (parseInt(x) == parseInt(trs[i].id))
                {
                   alert(x);
                }
            }
        }
```